# Outlook for Mac not showing attachments in preview pane

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I'm running a fully updated **Microsoft Office 2019** on an up to date Monterey installation on a Macbook Pro.

Today I noticed that I cannot see attachments in any of my emails, even emails that I had previously read with attachments.

In the list view, where I can see all my emails in my inbox, I can see the little paper clip icon that shows that an email has an attachment. When I open that email, there is no indication anywhere that there is an attachment. I am unable to open or view attachments.

If I open **the same email in the web version of Outlook** (outlook.office.com), **I can see the paper clip, and the attachments as usual.**

I suspect that there was some automatic update that has caused this. Does anyone know if this is some new feature or option that can be disabled somewhere? I have combed through the preferences but have not been able to find anything yet.

Comment: Do above suggestion help? How is your issue going now?

Comment: The issue is in another user's computer and I haven't been able to try the suggestion yet

Comment: Is there any updates now?

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, it seems that the update to the "new" version of outlook is a possible culprit as well. I just unclicked the "New Outlook" item, reconfigured, and everything is good.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1172815)

Comment: I do believe that this is a reasonable answer.  Identifying that the problem may be in a recent update and demonstrating that the problem is resolved by rolling back to a previous release is certainly valid.  This doesn't appear to be a "hypothetical"; it appears the user actually validated the issue resolution.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, here are some troubleshooting steps for your reference:

- Recreate outlook profile
- Run outlook in safe mode to check if there are some add-ins cause
  the issue.
- Follow below steps to check if the issue can be resolved:

1. Quit Outlook for Mac.
2. Locate the following files:"~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Preferences”
3. Move these. plist files to Trash, but do not empty Trash and delete the files.
4. Re-open Outlook, check whether the issue is resolved. If yes, you can delete the files mentioned above in Trash. Otherwise, please put the deleted files back to the old location.

A similar thread for your reference: [Outlook on Mac - Attachments in Mails not displaying](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-on-mac-attachments-in-mails-not-displaying/8e2e12b6-2525-4972-8b4b-b66d021be6c4)

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating Outlook - no change.
I tried using the Sync tool - no change.
I tried rebooting my Mac - no change.
I switched to Old Outlook - problem fixed.
I switched back to New Outlook - problem returned.
I'm using Old Outlook until further notice.

Mac OS: Big Sur 11.4

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173388)

Answer (score 0):

Only new update version is going to work. Outlook with Old Mac OS is not performing well.

**The most up-to-date version of OSx would work flawlessly**

Answer (score 0):

Someone else mentioned that is related to the New Outlook and that's correct.

For those who don't know where to remove it just

- go to Outloook Menu
- and click on "New Outlook" in order to remove the check mark,

that will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I tried uninstalling all my office apps and also manually cleaned cache and other related data but nothing worked.

At the end, I "reverted to legacy outlook" via:
Help Menu --> Revert to Legacy Outlook:
[image: screenshot of the option]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, I just made sure I had the latest OS and all was fine after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).